# Aligning SVG Progress Bar with Dynamic Diamond Shapes in Bootstrap Columns

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

[Here's what I'm essentially trying to re-create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omLgW.png)
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Sandmancer/pen/zYypRxx)

```
<div class="stepbar mx-4 container-fluid " id="stepbar" data-object-id="dsStages">
    <div class="stage mx-auto">
        <div class="scale">
            <svg class="arrowParent " viewBox="0 0 86.295 38.595" width="100%" height="100%">
                <path class="stepArrow" stroke-width="1"
                    d="M 0 0 H 74.09 L 84.295 19.185 L 74.325 37.595 H 0 L 8.955 18.68 L 0 0 Z"></path>
            </svg>

            <i class="stageName">Some name </i>
        </div>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" class="gateBorder  gateDiamond">
            <!--<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" class="gateBox col-5 gateDiamond" data-if="currentRow.GateEndOfPhase">-->
            <polygon points="20 25,45 50,70 25,45 0"
                data-class-if="!currentRow.GateName || !currentRow.GateEndOfPhase: hidden" />
            <text x="45" y="32" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14" data-field="GateName"
                data-class-if="!currentRow.GateEndOfPhase: hidden"></text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="stage mx-auto">
        <div class="scale">
            <svg class="arrowParent " viewBox="0 0 86.295 38.595" width="100%" height="100%">
                <path class="stepArrow" stroke-width="1"
                    d="M 0 0 H 74.09 L 84.295 19.185 L 74.325 37.595 H 0 L 8.955 18.68 L 0 0 Z"></path>
            </svg>

            <i class="stageName">Some name </i>
        </div>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" class="gateBorder  gateDiamond">
            <!--<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" class="gateBox col-5 gateDiamond" data-if="currentRow.GateEndOfPhase">-->
            <polygon points="20 25,45 50,70 25,45 0"
                data-class-if="!currentRow.GateName || !currentRow.GateEndOfPhase: hidden" />
            <text x="45" y="32" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14" data-field="GateName"
                data-class-if="!currentRow.GateEndOfPhase: hidden"></text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="stage mx-auto">
        <div class="scale">
            <svg class="arrowParent " viewBox="0 0 86.295 38.595" width="100%" height="100%">
                <path class="stepArrow" stroke-width="1"
                    d="M 0 0 H 74.09 L 84.295 19.185 L 74.325 37.595 H 0 L 8.955 18.68 L 0 0 Z"></path>
            </svg>

            <i class="stageName">Some name </i>
        </div>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" class="gateBorder  gateDiamond">
            <!--<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" class="gateBox col-5 gateDiamond" data-if="currentRow.GateEndOfPhase">-->
            <polygon points="20 25,45 50,70 25,45 0"
                data-class-if="!currentRow.GateName || !currentRow.GateEndOfPhase: hidden" />
            <text x="45" y="32" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14" data-field="GateName"
                data-class-if="!currentRow.GateEndOfPhase: hidden"></text>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" class="gateBorder gateDiamond clonedDiamond d-md-block "
        data-if="!currentRow.GateEndOfPhase">
        <polygon points="20 25,45 50,70 25,45 0" data-class-if="!currentRow.GateName : hidden"></polygon>
        <text x="45" y="32" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14" data-field="GateName"></text>
    </svg>
</div>


<script>
    function formatProgressBar() {
        var stages = []; //Array
        // var gateWidth = 220;
        // var gateWidth = document.getElementById('progressbarmain').offsetWidth - 50;
        // if (stages >= 5) {
        //     // Set the width of the step bar
        //     $("#stepbar").css("width", gateWidth * stages + "px");
        // }
        // else {
        //     // $("#stepbar").addClass('container');
        //     //  $("#stage").addClass('mx-2');
        // };

        // Reset
        var gates = $('.scale');
        // gates.addClass('d-none d-sm-flex');
        gates.removeClass("completed active selected pending text-primary");

        for (var i = 0; i < stages; i++) {
            var currentIndex = [] //array

            if (currentIndex === i) {
                gates.eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
            if (dsStages.getData(i).IsCurrentStage === true) {
                // var prevElement = gates.filter(function (index) { return index == i - 1; });
                gates.eq(i).addClass('selected');
                // gates.eq(i).removeClass('d-none d-sm-flex');
                // gates.eq(i + 1).removeClass('d-none d-sm-flex');
                // prevElement.removeClass('d-none d-sm-flex');

            }
            if (dsStages.getData(i, 'Status') === 'Completed') {
                gates.eq(i).addClass('completed text-primary  ');
            }
            else {
                gates.eq(i).addClass('pending ');
            }
        }
        var lastGate = gates.eq(stages - 1);
        $(".stageName").addClass("font-weight-bold");
    }

</script>

<style>
    .stepbar {
        z-index: 0;
        border: none;
        position: relative;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
        line-height: 1;
        max-width: inherit;
        height: fit-content;
    }

    .stage {
        fill: yellowgreen;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        z-index: -5;
        align-items: center;
        transition: transform 0.2s ease;
    }

    .scale {
        fill: yellowgreen;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        z-index: -5;
        align-items: center;
        transition: transform 0.2s ease;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .scale.scale.completed>i:after {
        content: " " "\f00c";
        font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    }

    .gateDiamond {
        z-index: 3;
        color: black;
        fill: #EACA2B;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-linejoin: bevel;

    }

    .gateDiamond text {
        fill: black;
        stroke: none;
    }



    .stageName {
        z-index: 8;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        user-select: none;
        text-align: center;
        transition: transform 0.2s ease;
        font-style: normal;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000,
            1px 1px 0 #000;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        font-size: 0.85vw;
        max-width: 60%;
        left: 20%;
        right: 20%;
    }

    .scale:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }

    .scale.active {
        transform: scale(1.2);
        transform-origin: center;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .scale.pending {
        fill: lightgray;
        fill: #E2F2FC;
    }

    .scale.selected {
        fill: #3078C2;
    }

    .scale.completed {
        fill: #3078C2;
    }
```

What I'm having trouble with is the having the the shapes center aligned, as the shapes goes out of bounds of the viewboxes. (or the viewboxes goes out of bounds of the bootstrap column system/container?)

Also I don't know how I'll dynamically get the last diamond shape to appear above the last stage class; without disrupting the rest of the progress bar. I guess we need to set the height after inserting. clonedDiamond (lastDiamond) somewhere in side the container/stepbar.

It is to be responsive (for medium-larger screens) phones aren't a concern right now. I use bootstrap for this, but the svg/polygons have weaknesses attached to it for this case.

Also there can be variable amount of steps(stage), fetched from a object array. .

- the Stages are the one to take precedent (largest shape)
- Diamonds are to be smaller, but still readable intervalling between the shape
- The Diamond for the last stage it is not to "precede" it , but be above it.
- The last diamond should still containted within the cointainer
- without disrupting the other shapes or going out of bounds.

--

- Can use jQuery
- Can use bootstrap
- Can use CSS if better/applicable
- I have tried to move away from svg/polygons to pure CSS shapes with borders. This had weaknesses with regards to bootstrap systems when I tried.
- Tried modifying the viewbox values to have better align with the goals.
- tried CSS clip paths, but had weaknesses making the text clip, of course.